# Formatting actions on a small selection of text with the contents of a textbox in a VBA user-form

Tags: excel, vba, richtextbox

I have a textbox  within a userform. I want to be able to  select a specific portion of text within this textbox and format it like a rich text- for example,  embolden it, add a bullet point etc. I am trying to create a command button to enable formatting of this sort. I am unsure of how to get VBA to embolden the selected portion of text. My code does not work.
Thank you

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    selectedtext_1 = TextBox1.SelText
    selectedtext_1.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
End Sub
```

Comment: You simply cannot format parts of a text in a Textbox.

Comment: Sorry, but like FunThomas said it's not possible to format just part of text in a TextBox. I know that it's not the same, but Text Box -shape on worksheet can contain rich text format.